# Matrix multiplication in CUDA running out of memory

Tags: python, cuda, gpu, numba

I try to compute the matrix multiplication using the script:

```
import numpy as np
import math
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from numba import cuda
from numba import *


def mult(a,b):
    return a*b
mult_gpu=cuda.jit(restype=float32,argtypes=[float32,float32],device=True)(mult)

@cuda.jit(argtypes=[float32[:,:],float32[:,:],float32[:,:,:]])
def mult_kernel(a,b,c):
    Ni=c.shape[0]
    Nj=c.shape[1]
    Nk=c.shape[2]

    startX,startY,startZ=cuda.grid(3)
    gridX=cuda.gridDim.x*cuda.blockDim.x
    gridY=cuda.gridDim.y*cuda.blockDim.y
    gridZ=cuda.gridDim.z*cuda.blockDim.z

    for i in range(startX,Ni,gridX):
        for j in range(startY,Nj,gridY):
            for k in range(startZ,Nk,gridZ):
                c[i,j,k]=mult_gpu(a[i,k],b[j,k])

def main():
    A=np.ones((20,50000),dtype=np.float32)
    B=np.ones((3072,50000),dtype=np.float32)
    C=np.ones((20,3072,50000),dtype=np.float32)
    (Ni,Nj,Nk)=C.shape

    my_gpu=cuda.get_current_device()
    thread_ct=my_gpu.WARP_SIZE
    block_ct_x=int(math.ceil(float(Ni)/thread_ct))
    block_ct_y=int(math.ceil(float(Nj)/thread_ct))
    block_ct_z=int(math.ceil(float(Nk)/thread_ct))

    blockdim=thread_ct,thread_ct,thread_ct
    griddim=block_ct_x,block_ct_y,block_ct_z
    print "Threads per block:",blockdim
    print "Blocks per grid:",griddim

    start=timer()
    Cg=cuda.to_device(C)
    mult_kernel[griddim,blockdim](A,B,Cg)
    Cg.to_host()
    dt=timer()-start
    print "Computation done in %f s"%(dt)

    print 'C[:3,1,1] = ',C[:3,1,1]
    print 'C[-3:,1,1] = ',C[-3:,1,1]


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Executing this yields an error:

```
numba.cuda.cudadrv.driver.CudaAPIError: [2] Call to cuMemAlloc results in CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
```

How could I fix this memory problem?

Nevertheless, using smaller matrices

```
    A=np.ones((20,500),dtype=np.float32)
    B=np.ones((372,500),dtype=np.float32)
    C=np.ones((20,372,500),dtype=np.float32)
```

there is still an error:

```
numba.cuda.cudadrv.driver.CudaAPIError: [1] Call to cuLaunchKernel results in CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE
```

I got inspired by the [Mandelbrot Example](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/harrism/f5707335f40af9463c43) to implement the computation above.

**EDIT1**

In order to resolve any confusion, this is actually a 3D matrix by 3D matrix multiplication:

```
    A=np.ones((20,1,50000),dtype=np.float32)
    B=np.ones((1,3072,50000),dtype=np.float32)
    C=np.ones((20,3072,50000),dtype=np.float32)
```

I skipped one dimension in `A` and `B` because it is not necessary for the computation.

**EDIT2**

My GPU is:

```
    In [1]: from numba import cuda

    In [2]: gpu=cuda.get_current_device()

    In [3]: gpu.name
    Out[3]: 'GeForce GT 750M'
```

**EDIT3**

According to the memory of my GPU (2GB), I reduced the size of each dimension by 2:

```
    dimx=10
    dimy=1536
    dimz=25000
    A=np.ones((dimx,dimz),dtype=np.float32)
    B=np.ones((dimy,dimz),dtype=np.float32)
    C=np.ones((dimx,dimy,dimz),dtype=np.float32)
```

But I still receive the `CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY` error. How could one explain this?

The calculation yields a size of about 1.7GB for the 3 matrices:
`(10*1536*25000*4.+10*25000*4+1536*25000*4.)/(10**9)=1.6906`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the first problem, you're running out of memory.  A major contributor to that is that this isn't the way people would normally do a matrix-matrix multiply.  Normally, as you are multiplying row and column elements together, you would keep a running sum, then store that sum in the appropriate location in the product (result) matrix.  This will allow you to have a much smaller size for the `c` matrix, ie. it need only be 2 dimensions, not 3.  You may wish to just study the linear algebra definition of matrix-matrix multiply.  When you multiply a 2D matrix by a 2D matrix, the result is a 2D matrix, not a 3D matrix.

In a nutshell, something like this:

```
for i in range(startX,Ni,gridX):
    for j in range(startY,Nj,gridY):
        c[i,j] = 0
        for k in range(startZ,Nk,gridZ):
            c[i,j]= c[i,j] + mult_gpu(a[i,k],b[j,k])
```

And adjust your `c` shape accordingly.

If you actually need the individual products in 3D form as you are doing here, then there is not much I can say except that you will need to scale the problem to fit in the GPU memory size for whatever GPU you are using.

Regarding the second problem, you have a problem here:

```
thread_ct=my_gpu.WARP_SIZE
...

blockdim=thread_ct,thread_ct,thread_ct
```

`WARP_SIZE` is 32 (presumably) so you are asking for a 3D block of dimensions 32*32*32 = 32K threads.  But CUDA threadblocks are limited to a maximum of 1024 threads, which limit is the product of the individual dimensions.

If you change your thread_ct to 8, for example:

```
thread_ct=8
```

You should be able to get past this particular issue.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the second problem!
Regarding the matrix multiplication, it was actually a 3D by 3D matrix multiplication.. I just skipped one dimension because it's not necessary for the computation. I add an edit on that.
Could you please explain what "scaling the problem to fit in the GPU" means?

Comment: Your `A`, `B`, `C` arrays all will need to fit in GPU memory.  You can find out how much memory your GPU has by running the `deviceQuery` CUDA sample code.  An output array of `C=np.ones((20,3072,50000),dtype=np.float32)` for example would require 20*3072*50000*4 bytes (float32 = 4 bytes).  That one array alone of that size would occupy approximately 12GB.  If your GPU had for example 8GB, you would need to reduce the size of your problem until all 3 matrices A,B,C could fit in 8GB together.  In fact your GT750m may have something like 4GB of memory (or less, possibly).

Comment: According to my System Report `NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2048 MB` it is only 2GB. So, I would have to split each of the matrices into 7 parts: `(20*3072*50000*4.+20*50000*4.+3072*50000*4.)/(2*10**9)=6.4532`. And then run the kernel function `mult_kernel` 7 times. Please correct me, if this is wrong. Thank you very much, now I see where I have to investigate further.

Comment: Yes, although for simplicity I would probably split it into 8 parts, not 7.  I had sort of assumed that this question was a "learning exercise" because a lot of questions like this on SO are.   However I'm a bit skeptical that this avenue you are pursuing will be interesting from a performance standpoint.  If it's just a learning exercise - great, have at it.  If you're doing this because you want to speed something up, you might be disappointed.

Comment: Well, it's actually both. I want to understand how to use CUDA and see if I can speed up a computation that takes about 30 sec on CPU. 
However, I am still not solving the memory problem, even by reducing each dimension of the matrices by 2, I make an edit above. Am I still missing something?

Comment: Your GT750m is hosting a display, probably (on your laptop) and so the actual memory it has is less than 2GB.   I don't know how much the display is using up (and CUDA/Numba overhead), but it might only have 1 or 1.5GB of memory actually available. The total required for all 3 matrices is about 12GB, so you would need 1.5GB available if you divide by 8, and its possible you have less than 1.5GB available.  You can get an idea by running `nvidia-smi` at a command prompt.  Anyway, maybe try dividing by 16 instead of 8.  That should get you down to 0.75GB, and you should have that much available.

Comment: I see your edit now.  You probably don't have 1.7GB available.

Comment: You're right, I did not have the full memory of my GPU for usage. Well, it was not the display. I was running an IPython shell where I referenced the GPU. Somehow this took quite a lot of the memory. Now, I finally can compute the multiplication with the values in Edit3, takes about 4.6 sec.